# How to let only one thread to run a critical section while discarding the other threads without hang

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

I'm developing a windows service with .NET framework 4.0 and C#.

This service will open a socket to receive commands.

I have this socket listener class:

```
public class SocketListener
{
    private System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener m_server;

    public SQLServerSocketListener()
    {
        IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5445);
        m_server = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener(ip);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        m_server.Start();
        m_server.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new AsyncCallback(Callback), m_server);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (m_server != null)
            m_server.Stop();
    }

    private void Callback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        if (!(m_server.Server.IsBound) ||
            (m_server.Server == null))
            return;

        TcpClient client;
        try
        {
            client = m_server.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            //Listener canceled
            return;
        }
        DataHandler dataHandler = new DataHandler(client);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(dataHandler.HandleClient, client);

        m_server.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new AsyncCallback(Callback), m_server);
    }
}
```

And this class to process the commands received through the socket:

```
class DataHandler
{
    private bool m_disposed = false;
    private TcpClient m_controlClient;

    private IPEndPoint m_remoteEndPoint;
    private string m_clientIP;

    private NetworkStream m_controlStream;
    private StreamReader m_controlReader;

    public DataHandler(TcpClient client)
    {
            m_controlClient = client;
    }

    public void HandleClient(object obj)
    {
            m_remoteEndPoint = (IPEndPoint)m_controlClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint;

            m_clientIP = m_remoteEndPoint.Address.ToString();

            m_controlStream = m_controlClient.GetStream();

            m_controlReader = new StreamReader(m_controlStream, true);

            string line;
            try
            {
                    while (((line = m_controlReader.ReadLine()) != null) ||
                            (m_controlClient == null) ||
                            (!m_controlClient.Connected))
                    {
                            CommandHandler.ProcessCommand(line);
                    }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                    Console.WriteLine("CodeServerService.DataHandler error: {0}", ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                    Dispose();
            }
    }
}
```

And, the CommandHandler:

```
class CommandHandler
{
    public static void ProcessCommand(string command, string connStringINICIC, string connStringTRZIC, byte codeLevel)
    {
        switch (command)
        {
            case "GetNewCodes<EOF>":
                CodesIncremental.GetNewCodes();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And `CodesIncremental`:

```
public class CodesIncremental
{
    public static bool GetNewCodes()
    {
        [ ... ]
    }
}
```

My problem is that I can receive `GetNewCodes<EOF>` command before the first one finish. So, I need to don't let `GetNewCodes<EOF>`runs if there is another `GetNewCodes<EOF>` running.

How can I don't let run `CodesIncremental.GetNewCodes();` if this code its running in another thread?

I need something to discard the commands received while `CodesIncremental.GetNewCodes();` is running.

In pseudo code:

If `CodesIncremental.GetNewCodes();` is running do nothing.

Comment: the lock from JoaoFSA might work - but I would strongly advise to redesign the system to use some kind of Queue to handle the incomming requests

Comment: @CarstenKönig I have updated my question with more details. I need to discard any command received while CodesIncremental.GetNewCodes(); is running.

Comment: I would say you totall yhandle the absolutely wrong thing. The architecture is substandard. If you use a Select, process handlers, a data queue the whole issue never even comes up. You fix symboms of a bad object model, instead of fixing the object model.

Comment: @TomTom Well, show me how you would.

Comment: @VansFannel Sorry, but I am not putting up a post with 10+ pages of code and writing your server for you. I do that stuff for a living and I do have enough pride to tell you to learn programming. Read up on the scalable API's (Select in particular to select which of a list of sockets have data waiting) and on message and work queues. Look up how IIS works (similar concept). Explaining basic scalable architecture is way beyond the scope of thie site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version does not block. [`CompareExchange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/801kt583%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ensures atomicity, so only one thread will swap the value of the `_running` variable, the rest of threads will just return inmediately.

```
public class CodesIncremental
{
    static Int32 _running = 0;

    public static bool GetNewCodes()
    {
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _running, 1, 0) == 1)
            return false;

        try
        {
            // Do stuff...
            return true;
        }
        finally
        {
            _running = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

A difference than monitors or other synchronization methods, there is little contention on this method, and it is quite faster.

Comment: shouldn't he also use one of the interlocked methods to reset the flag to 0 ?

Comment: You don't need atomicity to set a 32 bits value. You need it when you have to compare and set, because something could change the value between those two operations, or when setting a 64 bits value on a 32 bits processor, because it would require two operations. To set a 32 bits value is a single operation.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Update to address the modification of the question.

A simple way is to use the [Monitor.TryEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4tssbxcw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Monitor.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.exit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
Just call the ExecuteGetNewCodeCommand for the processing of your "GetNewCode" command.

```
object _myLock = new object();

void ExecuteGetNewCodeCommand( ArgType args)
{
    bool result = false;   

    try
    {
        result = Monitor.TryEnter(_myLock); // This method returns immediately

        if( !result)  // check if the lock is acquired. 
            return;

        // Execute your command code here
    }
    finally
    {
         if(result)     // release the lock.
             Monitor.Exit(_myLock);
    }       
 }
```

**Old answer (before the modification of the question):**
Think about using a queue and a Thread Pool.
Every time you receive a new Command (including "GetNewCode") insert it into a queue. In addition, you will have a Thread Pool that will read requests from the queue and execute them.
If you are using only one thread in the Thread pool, or a dedicated thread for this type of commands (where there are other threads for other requests/commands in the queue/queus), then only one "GetNewCode" request will be running at the same time.

This way you can control the number of threads your server will run. Thus, also the resources your server uses.

If you just synchronize (via locks or other mechanism) then there are a performance penalties. And maybe a denial of service, if you reached a thread limit. Let's say for somehow the execution of a request is taking too long (Maybe a deadlock in your code). If you will not use a Thread pool, and will execute the commands/requests on the same thread the client connected to your, then your sever may hang.

Though, If you will synchronize the threads inside the thread pool, then the server will not hang. Maybe it will be really slow to execute the requests, but it will still run and work.

There is a default .Net ThreadPool implementation at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as.aspx).

Comment: I have updated my question with more details. I need to discard any command received while CodesIncremental.GetNewCodes(); is running.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this using [AutoResetEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.autoresetevent?view=net-6.0):

```
public class CodesIncremental
{
    private AutoResetEvent _event = new AutoResetEvent(true);

    public static bool GetNewCodes()
    {
        if(!_event.WaitOne(0))
           return true; //is running
        try
        {
        /*
           actions in case if isn't running
        */
        }
        finally
        {
         _event.Set();
        }
        return false;

    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is better to add Try-Catch clauses. Otherwise, he may never reset the vent if an exception occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Add a lock to your CodesIncremental Class:

```
public class CodesIncremental
{
    private object m_threadLock = new object();

    public static bool GetNewCodes()
    {
        lock(m_threadLock)
        {
        [ ... ]
        }
    }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

This way when your GetNewCodes method is called the first time the 'lock' statement will get an exclusive lock on the 'm_threadLock' object and only release it when the execution leaves the lock block, if any other thread calls the methods while the first thread is still inside the lock block it will not be able to get an exclusive lock and execution will suspend until it can.

Update:
Since you want to discard other calls try this:

```
public class CodesIncremental
{
    private static object m_threadLock = new object();
    private static bool m_running = false;

    public static bool GetNewCodes()
    {
        lock(m_threadLock)
        {
            if(m_running)
            {
                return;
            }
            m_running  = true;
        }
        try
        {
            [ ... ]
        }
        finally
        {
            m_running  = false;
        }
    }
}
```

there might be better ways but this should do the trick.

Update 2: Hadn't seen the static

Comment: I'm sorry, I have updated my question with more details. I need to discard any command received while `CodesIncremental.GetNewCodes();` is running.

Comment: Edited the answer but do you want to discard all commands of just the GetNewCodes?

Comment: Only the `GetNewCodes`.

Comment: Then the code in my update should work, the method will be called a 2nd time but will just exit immediately if the first call hasn't reached the 'm_running  = false;'

Comment: @m1o2 you are right the lock is still necessary, corrected